# ERROR running force:mdapi:deploy: versions.map is not a function

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-error

After converting our SFDX project into a mdapi one, we are getting the error below when trying to deploy using the "sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -l RunLocalTests -c -d ./src -u full -w -1" command.

```
ERROR running force:mdapi:deploy:  versions.map is not a function
```

$ sfdx --version
sfdx-cli/7.165.0 win32-x64 node-v16.17.0

Any ideas?

I have tried downgrading the sfdx-cli and I'm still facing the issue.

Comment: Try using force:auth:web:login and logging in again. That's what fixed my recent issue.

Comment: It worked :) !!!! Thanks... You may want to post this as an answer... Thanks, @sfdcfox!